# Windows-Android display streaming without internet

Tags: windows, android

I searched all over but could not get a good software for it. I want to mirror my windows 7 display to my android phone over WiFi or plain USB. I do not want to involve the internet here( no data usage).
Can you guys tell me a way or recommend any software for this? I have java and android developing tools installed. It would be great if that software doesn't require me to install NET framework or other time consuming stuff.

Comment: I'm not using Windows, so I cannot give a first-hand recommendation. But there are several apps available to [use Android as your second monitor](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists.php?topic=cat;id=148#group_652) or [access your Windows desktop via RDP](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists.php?topic=cat;id=148#group_656) (RDP is the standard Remote Desktop Protocol shipping with Windows).

Comment: Why do you want to do this display mirroring?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [RealVNC](https://www.realvnc.com/) (and more generally most VNC and other remote control solutions):

- Non-free
- Secure connection
- View on multiple monitors ([since version 4.2](https://www.realvnc.com/products/vnc/documentation/4.2/release-notes/))
- Easy to use
- Windows/Mac/Linux for server, Windows/Mac/Linux/[Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.realvnc.viewer.android) for client
- you can configure the server to be view only.